# Debug remote Grails application with jvisualvm

Tags: tomcat, grails, amazon-ec2, remote-debugging, jvisualvm

I have a Grails 2 application deployed on Tomcat 7, running on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance. What are the minimum steps required to remotely debug/monitor the app via an SSH connection, for example using jvisualvm (which ships with the JDK)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, so documenting it for later use. Note that this example doesn't use any authentication nor SSL on Tomcat's end. With a little tweaking, this should apply to non-Ubuntu instances as well.

**1. On the remote machine, enable JMX by adding to Tomcat's JAVA_OPTS:**

In `/etc/default/tomcat7`, append the existing JAVA_OPTS:

```
JAVA_OPTS = "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098"
```

Then restart Tomcat to apply the changes:

`sudo service tomcat7 restart`

**2.On the local machine:**

SSH to the remote machine and create a SOCKS tunnel in local port 10000. (This will open a normal-looking SSH prompt to the remote machine, but also print additional debugging logs in the session.)

`ssh -v -D 10000 <hostname>`

Start jvisualvm. The parameters are for added memory and making jvisualvm aware of the compiled Grails classes, with *target/classes* relative to the Grails application directory:

`jvisualvm -J-Xms1G -J-Xmx1G -cp:a target/classes`

Configure jvisualvm to use the proxy we created:

```
Prefences > Network
Add SOCKS proxy: hostname: localhost, port: 10000
No Proxy hosts: (make empty)
```

Here I use a 'Local connection' just to avoid a hostname conflict between local and remote connections.

```
Right-click on Local > "Add JMX connection" > localhost:1098
```

That's it – now you should be able to monitor to your remote Grails application.